# Multiple choice UI control if number of options is known at run time

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have component that can be installed for different instances of SQL server. I want to show user all available instances and give him ability to choose the instances he likes. I have troubles choosing right UI approach for that purpose. 
Ideal decision would be list with checkboxes but WIX does not support this control. Give me please any suggestion on how to organised UI if number of options is known at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

If using Wix 3.7 look at using WixBalExtensionExt.dll at Wixextba.codeplex.com (which is now also available as new featues in Wix 3.8.  Or write a managed bootstrapper application. Either way a Wix Bundle is the answer.